# Why does int give a garbage value of 8 digits here?

Tags: c

I understand `b` will get a garbage value, but it should be in the range of int. Am I wrong?

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>

    void main()
    {
        int a = 300, b, c;
        if (a >= 400)
            b = 300;
        c = 200;
        printf("\n%d%d", b, c);

        getch();
    }
```

Output in Borland C++ compiler:

```
23603264200
```

Comment: Are you testing if people can figure out the puzzle?

Answer (score 3):

You don't print a space between them

b = 23603264 and
c = 200, both are in valid ranges of an int.

For reference max value of 4 byte SIGNED int is about 2.7b

Comment: Nice observation, I missed that

Comment: @cnicutar Yeah it took me a sec and then I looked at the print statement a little closer.

Comment: but how can u say 23603264 is in the range of int. The max value that int can store in 16 bit compiler is 65536

Comment: @deepaklearner Are you sure that you're correctly specifying to compile 16 bit? I don't even think that platforms support 16 bit anymore and it's probably just compiling it as 32 bit anyway.

Comment: i have studied int is of two bits not 4 bits.

Comment: so printf("%d\n", sizeof(int)); will print 2?

Comment: u r right. sizeof(float) should give 8 but its giving 4 in my borland c++ compiler

Comment: double is 8 bytes, float is 4

Comment: so u mean the value of int only depends on the operating system. Float and double remain constant for 16 bit or 32 bit os.

Comment: Yes, it also depends on the hardware. Most 16 bit software is probably just run in 32 bit compatibility mode where the values are 32 bit extended so you can have valid sizes (to prevent unaligned access and other things that come from different sized memory regions). Which explains why the garbage value is a 32 bit sized int.

Comment: plz clarify me float and double do not depend on hardware.

Comment: I meant for certain values hardware is a factor, such as void *, long, long long, etc...

Answer (score 2):

When you first declare `b`, it isn't initialized to any value, and it's only set to `300` if `a >= 400`, which it isn't.

So the output is really: 23603264 200

And 200 is `c`, but you didn't put a space in your output, i.e. `printf("%d %d\n", b, c);`

And the 23603264 is whatever is interpreted as an `int` from the memory where `b` is.

Answer (score 2):

Let's step through your code.

```
int a=300,b,c;
```

We have three `int` variables: `a`, set to `300`, and also `b` and `c`, which contain the unknown contents of the memory they occupy because you didn't define the value of them. Stack and heap memory is not initialised to any particular value unless you explicitly do so.

```
if(a>=400)
b=300;
```

If `a` is greater than or equal to `400`, set `b` to `300`. Hang on! `a` is never greater than `400`, because you set it to `300`! Therefore, `b` remains some random value.

```
c=200;
```

Set `c` to `200`.

```
printf("\n%d%d",b,c);
```

This will print "(some random number here)200", with no space in between.

---

I've just realised that I didn't really answer your question in the text above. The reason why the number appears to be bigger than the range of an `int` is because the number you see is actually `b` and `c`, next to each other, without a space in between.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your int is at least 32 bit - so 23603264 fits in that range (last 200 komes from c which was initialized properly )